# How to integrate by parts in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, spherical-coordinates, integration

I'm running into some troubles with the integration of a spherically symmetric 3D function. 
I'm having the following expression to evaluate :
$$
I=\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^\pi \sin\theta d\theta\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} r^2 dr
$$

where the generic function $f$ only depends on the radius $r$. If I where in Cartesian coordinates, there wouldn't be any $r^2$ term and the integral would be 0 provided that $f$ vanishes at infinity (which is ok).

Now, in spherical coordinates, this does not seem to be true. If I integrate first over the angles, I get a factor $4\pi$ in front of the radial integral. I can then integrate by parts to remove the partial derivative and I obtain :
$$
I=-8\pi\int_0^\infty f(r)r dr
$$
as the boundary terms vanish if $f(r) \rightarrow 0$.

At first sight, this seems to be correct. However, when looking at the definition of integration by parts in $R^n$:

$$
\int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} v \,d\Omega = \int_{\Gamma} u v \, \nu_i \,d\Gamma - \int_{\Omega} u \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i} \, d\Omega
$$

Where $\nu_i$ is a unit vector on $\Gamma$ the boundary of $\Omega$.
My previous computation does not seem to be right. The $r^2$ term is part of the integration measure $d\Omega$ and should thus not be taken into account for the "derivative-swap". This would mean that my first integral is $0$ for all functions $f$ that behave nicely and vanish sufficiently fast as $\rightarrow\infty$.
$$
I= \left| f(r) r^2 \right|_{r=0}^{r=\infty} = 0
$$

Which (if any) of the two version is correct ?

Do you know any good reference on integration by parts in non-cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Your first version seems to be correct for me (with taking Tim's remark into account). But I dont understand your second version. However try to look at these key words : Stock' formula, Green-Ostrogradsky formula, divergence (these are the generalisation of the integration by part in $R^n$ ($n \geq 2$)).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
The first version uses integration by part on the real line.
The second version is exactly Ostrogradsky formula in $R^n$ if you take the divergence of $uv$. 
My concern is that both formula do not lead to the same result.

Comment: Are you still looking for some more information about this Nanoc?  If you could explain what is sill missing for you, perhaps I could help.

Answer (score 4):

The "integration by parts" formula you cited applies to an integral over a 2D surface, this does not apply to an integral of a function over $\mathbb{R}^3$. Your integral $I$ is as simple as it looks, the integration over $r$ is just an ordinary one-dimensional integral over $[0, \infty)$, the fact that you got there by using polar coordinates does not matter.

You can apply the integration by parts formula as you did. (For the boundary terms to vanish you actually need $r^2 f(r)$ to be zero for $r=0$ and for $r \to \infty$.)

BTW: If the original problem is about integrating a function that does depend on $r$ only, then there is a $sin(\theta)$ missing in your formula for $I$, from the Jacobian of the transformation of 3D cartesian coordinates to 3D spherical coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The $\sin\theta$ is missing.

Mmmh. But that does sound quite contradictory. You tell me that both my formula are correct. 
Does this mean that integrating any derivative with respect to the radius of a radial function gives 0. At least if $r^2f(r) \rightarrow 0$ at the boundaries ?

Even if I cannot find a counter-exemple, this does not sound right to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think a perspective on this that might help clarify things is to view integration by parts not as linked to any particular form of integral but as a rather trivial implication of the product rule for differentiation. The product rule $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$ is correct regardless of what other factors or integrations surround it. So all of these are correct:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int (uv)'\mathrm dr
&=&
\int u'v\mathrm dr+\int uv'\mathrm dr\;,
\\
\int (uv)'r^2\mathrm dr
&=&
\int u'vr^2\mathrm dr+\int uv'r^2\mathrm dr\;,
\\
\int (ur^2)'\mathrm dr
&=&
\int u'r^2\mathrm dr+2\int ur\mathrm dr\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

The first and last are more useful because you can get rid of the integration on the left-hand side, but the middle one is also correct. So there’s nothing sophisticated going on that has anything to with the interplay of integration and differentiation, except in the step where you cancel integration and differentiation on the left-hand side. The analogous version of your “definition of integration by parts in $\mathbb R^n$” is

$$
\int_\Omega\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(uv)\,\mathrm d\Omega=\int_\Omega\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}v\,\mathrm d\Omega+\int_\Omega u\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}\mathrm d\Omega\;.
$$

To get what you wrote from this trivial consequence of the product rule, you need

$$\int_\Omega\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\,\mathrm d\Omega=\int_\Gamma f\,\nu_i\,\mathrm d\Gamma\;.$$

That looks right to me if $x_i$ are the Cartesian coordinates. I don’t think it applies in general coordinates, so I don’t see how it could lead to a contradiction with what you did, but in any case, the point at which to sort this out is here, in applying the divergence theorem, and not in some separate “definition” of integration by parts, which is always just trivial product differentiation in reverse.